# How to Translate CURL to Python Requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am currently trying to integrate Stripe Connect and have come across the flowing CURl POST request:

```
curl https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
   -d client_secret=SECRET_CODE \
   -d code="{AUTHORIZATION_CODE}" \
   -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

However I am very new to CURL and have been doing some research and trying to use the requests package to do it. This is what my current code looks like:

```
data = '{"client_secret": "%s", "code": "%s", "grant_type": "authorization_code"}' % (SECRET_KEY, AUTHORIZATION_CODE) 
response = requests.post('https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token', json=data)
```

However this always returns a response code 400. I have no idea where I am going wrong and any guidance would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually sending json? Or just plaintext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are passing your `data` as string, instead `json` param of `requests.post` call expects it to be [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict). Your code should be:

```
import requests

data = {
     "client_secret": SECRET_KEY, 
     "code": AUTHORIZATION_CODE, 
     "grant_type": "authorization_code"
} 

response = requests.post('https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token', json=data)
```

Take a look at request library's [More complicated POST requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) document.